# Npm Install is Failing (Could not resolve dependency)

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When i try to do `npm install` i get the following:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: foliosure@1.0.1
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.8.29
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   zone.js@"~0.8.26" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer zone.js@"~0.8.26" from @angular/core@7.2.16
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!     @angular/core@"~7.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/core@"^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0" from primeng_latest@11.2.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/primeng_latest
npm ERR!       primeng_latest@"npm:primeng@^11.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/common, @angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer zone.js@"^0.10.2" from primeng_latest@11.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/primeng_latest
npm ERR!   primeng_latest@"npm:primeng@^11.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
```

This is my `package.json` dependencies file:

```
  "dependencies": 
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/d3": "^5.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "codemirror": "^5.58.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "^9.0.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.2.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.2.0",
    "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
    "primeng": "^7.0.5",
    "primeng_latest": "npm:primeng@^11.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
```

I tried downgrading the versions but it still gives the error. I also tried to google the solution but didn't find the right solution, would appreciate any help, Thank you.

Comment: "devDependencies": 
        "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^7.4.3",
        "@angular-builders/dev-server": "~7.3.1",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.2",
        "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.13.0",
        "@angular-devkit/core": "^11.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
        "ng-packagr": "^4.2.0",
        "primeng": "^6.1.7",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tsickle": ">=0.34.0",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~3.2.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"

Comment: You have package-lock.json file try following command: npm ci, If it still fails delete package-lock.json and node_modules folder and then try npm i command.

Comment: Thanks Rohit Dalal, but it didnt work, getting the same error.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Looks like it's a problem with Peer Dependencies try with npm install `--legacy-peer-deps`.

Comment: Thank You! Solved ```npm install @formkit/auto-animate``` install issue.

Comment: I ran this and went from 1 error to 45 errors

Comment: @Markus please tell the rest of us how you solved those, thanks

Comment: iirc it was a matter of deleting the node modules folder and making sure all versions in package.json lined up with the versions that the dependencies expected

Answer (score 34):

You can skip peer dependency conflict checks by running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` or you can set `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true` and then run `npm install` once again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the angular code of your friend in your machine then follow the steps.

step 1: this can be happen due to version mismatch in your node version and your friends node version and npm version.
C://projectFolder> node --version
then
C://projectFolder> npm -v

step 2: If the version is mismatch then uninstall node in your machine then restart then install the node version of your friend.

step 3:
run the below code  example

1.

```
npm install npm@[version]
```

in my machine

```
npm install -g npm@6.2.0
```

2. now run npm install in your project folder

   npm install
3. now npm start or ng serve to work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

in your case, the library `primeng_latest` has a peer dependency `zone.js` but expects it to be version `0.10.2` or above ( 0.10+ ) and your root version of that dependency is `0.8.29` (which is lower)

**One solution** is to update your root `zone.js` to `^0.10.2` instead of your current `~0.8.26`.

This should fix this particular issue because all other peer dependencies would tolerate the change in version:

```
npm install zone.js@^0.10.2
```